# How to prevent the termination of parent.bat before child.bat get finishes

Tags: java, batch-file, concurrency, process

I am using a java code to generate jasper report by executing a .bat file.

My java code uses process.waitsfor() until the process gets finished.

My java code

```
builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", batFilePath, reportName, tmpParFilePath, exportFilePath);
p = builder.start();
//um using  threads to consume p.ErrorStream and p.InputStream
p.waitFor();
```

In my parent.bat file, I am calling to child.bat file and I don't want to terminate the parent.bat file before child.bat file finishes.

This is my parent.bat file

```
@echo off
SET CURRENT_DIR_PATH=%~dp0
rem Parameters (%1 = Report Name, %2 = Non-standard Parameters File, %3 = Export File Name)
%CURRENT_DIR_PATH%reportViewer.bat %1.jasper %2 %3
exit 0
```

And this is my child.bat file

```
rem @echo off
rem Parameters (%1 = Report Name, %2 = Non-standard Parameters File)

SET PLANON_JVM_PATH=.\jre\bin
SET VIEWER_JAR_PATH=aia-bi-tools-reportmanager-1.1.jar
SET REPORTS_DIR_PATH=..\reports
SET DATASOURCE_CONFIG_FILE=jdbc.conf
SET PARAMETERS_DIR_PATH=..\reports
SET CURRENT_DIR_PATH=%~dp0

%PLANON_JVM_PATH%\java -jar %CURRENT_DIR_PATH%%VIEWER_JAR_PATH% - 
R%CURRENT_DIR_PATH%%REPORTS_DIR_PATH%\%1 - 
C%CURRENT_DIR_PATH%%DATASOURCE_CONFIG_FILE% -P%2 -E%3
exit 0
```

What are the changes are required to make for .bat files to accomplish the above requirement

Comment: Type `call /?`.

Comment: call %CURRENT_DIR_PATH%reportViewer.bat %1.jasper %2 %3 like this?

Comment: when uses "call" it generates an empty report. but I think its not passing arguments. @CatCat

Comment: Call passes arguments. That's not it. Also REM your echo off in the first batch file as you have done in the second. Then post all output.

Comment: still, it generates an empty report. But when I remove process.waitfor from java code it generates the report. @CatCat.

Comment: I can only comment on the batchfile part.

Comment: Thank you very much @CatCat. Bdw  Is it okay to use exit 0 ?

Comment: Type `exit /?`. I suspect you should delete the line.

Comment: Commands like `start` and `exit` are about changing normal behaviour. They are not used unless you need to override the normal behaviour of batch.

Comment: I removed exit command for both bat files. But I think without exit command it doesn't return to my java code and the program started to hang. Anyway your help is really appreciated :)

Comment: You MUST use `call` when batch files start batch files.

Comment: Okay sure. Thank you

Comment: You cannot put all the options onto multiple lines without escaping the end of the line.

Comment: But this worked fine.